# Want to replace dual boot OS with a different OS; how can I find out which OS occupies which partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a dual boot Linux system with Ubuntu/OpenSuse.

How do I determine which OS occupies which partition?

Comment: I like lots of details: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  But you can just boot into each install and see what `mount` shows.

Comment: Mount the partition and look inside etc/issue

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

One option would be obtain the info from the [Boot Info Report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) or simply boot each distro and check the output of `mount|grep " / "` as suggested by oldfred [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062703/want-to-replace-dual-boot-os-with-different-os-howto-find-out-which-os-occupies#comment1739875_1062703)

Edit: `sudo fdisk -l` will also show you the mount points and boot flags as will gparted.

Another would be to boot from live media, mount the partition in question and issue the command `cat /mountpoint/etc/issue` where mountpoint is the point where you mounted it as suggested by Panther [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062703/want-to-replace-dual-boot-os-with-different-os-howto-find-out-which-os-occupies#comment1739915_1062703)

Another method would be to check the grub configuration. If you are more comfortable with a GUI you can install [grub customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) and launch that. Go to the list configuration tab, right click on the menu entry that you want to know about and click edit. Look for the line in the menu entry that begins with `linux   /boot/vmlinuz` and look what it says after `root=` You have now identified where that menu entry boots from. If anything about this answer is unclear please leave me a comment and I'll clarify to the best of my ability.